# Any way to enable dynamic/automatic brightness adjustment?

Tags: laptop, screen, brightness, thinkpad, backlight

My Lenovo ThinkPad X201 Tablet has a very bright screen (400 nits!), which is good for when objects on the screen are dark (say a night scene in a movie), but it is of course very blinding when objects are bright/white. I find myself continuously changing the brightness when watching a movie/video like this, and it is quite annoying.

Is there any utility available that will automatically change display brightness depending on if objects on screen are bright or dark? I know this is an option built into some desktop monitors (in the form of Dynamic Contrast I believe), but I have not found the same kind of thing for laptops.

To clarify, I would like a utility (or simple script, even) that turns the brightness (as in the backlight) up when the majority of stuff on screen is dark/black, and dims the brightness down when the majority of stuff on screen is bright/white, to take full advantage of this bright screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you find some option?

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo I don't believe I ever found a solution to this. Most existing dynamic contrast solutions actually work inverse from this (dimming backlight during dark scenes and brighter when light, for increased contrast effect).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [WildGuppy](http://www.thecutestgeek.com/wildguppy) which will adjust your brightness according to the light it gets from your webcam (not according to your screen content though).

[image: WildGuppy]

Comment: its not working properlly

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

You will see the brightness controller:

[image: brightness controller]